# MariaDB - online move/archive tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, myisam, rsyslog

We have a script that "rotates"/archive the Syslog tables in MySQL. This script:

- **at Linux level**, renames the "MyISAM" tables files then compress them
  then
- **inside MySQL**, rename these tables

The 2 steps are "online". No MySQLd restart is required.

Now I built a new Syslog database in **MariaDB** (Debian Stretch). The tables are using InnoDB and not MyISAM. This script fails at the 2nd execution to rename the table inside MySQL after moving the file:

*ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'SystemEvents_1' already exists*

A reference of the table is kept somewhere (tablespace internal system table?) which prevents from doing that.

My question: 
would it work if I migrate my tables to the ARIA engine with transactional=0?

Thanks, Vince

Comment: From my understanding, and since innoDB do not use a file per table(unless innodb_file_per_table is enabled), you can't do the same thing as with MyISAM...

Comment: thanks @Hackerman. I am going to look at the "innodb_file_per_table" option. My general feeling is that I should remain with InnoDB even if loosing syslog with the MyISAM/aria engine would not be a big deal...

Comment: And I think that even enabling that option, innoDB still is going to use the ibdata1 file...I suggest you to read this Q&A from the dba site https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/why-does-innodb-store-all-databases-in-one-file

Comment: Thanks for the link. This option seems to be enabled by default in MariaDB. I don't see any ibdata1 file but the table files SystemEvents and SystemEventsProperties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is no longer possible.
I converted my tables to MyISAM (and even Aria with transactional=0) and had the same error message. I think the best is to use mysqldump to export the tables instead of directly renaming the filesystem files. Less convenient but mysqldump will always work regardless the choosen engine.